# How to remove tax from "Shipping and Handling Charges" in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

On the cart page I am having data according to below:

```
Subtotal (Excl GST)     $39.90
Shipping & Handling (Freight)   $5.93
TAX     $4.53(10% of (39.90 + 5.93)).
```

But, i want `TAX` to be `3.99(10% 0f 39.90)`.
Here TAX has been applied on Shipping + Subtotal. But, i want tax to be applied only on Subtotal not on shipping charges. I believe there could be some configuration on backend side. Anyone could please suggest how can i resolve above scenario ?

Thanks,
Jen

Answer (score 0):

Check under Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Rules

You can read more here as this question was asked before:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36305/include-shipping-method-in-vat-calculation

Comment: I dont think question is the same one. But, i got the solution that i would have to select the class for the shipping as None in the Tax Configuration. Thanks Anyway :)